# How to find the mis-matched element against list of regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out the certain element, which is not present in the list.

say, i have `l1` consists of regexes (some pattern)

```
l1 = ["file.log","sample.log","abc_log_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_test-analysis.log","abc_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_sample-analysis.log"]


# l1 consisting regexes are of standard set of files.

test1 = ["file.log","sample.log","abc_log_123_12_12_test-analysis.log","abc_145_20_20_sample-analysis.log"]
```

Say `test1` is the test-list, which is to be compared with `l1` to check if all the files are generated. `In this case all files are present.`

Similarly, `test2 = ["file.log","abc_145_20_20_sample-analysis.log"]`
When `test2` is compared with `l1`, it should be notified that `sample.log` and file ending with `test-analysis.log` files are not generated.

```
    How can this be done with minimum complexity ?
```

Please find below code

```
import re

l1 = ["file.log","sample.log","abc_log_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_test-analysis.log","abc_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_sample-analysis.log"]
test1 = ["file.log","sample.log","abc_log_123_12_12_test-analysis.log","abc_145_20_20_sample-analysis.log"]
#test1 = ["file.log","abc_145_20_20_sample-analysis.log"]

for i in l1:
    flag = ""
    tmp = []
    for j in test1:
        if re.match("^"+str(i)+"$",j):
            flag = "yes"
            tmp.append(True)
            print "File {} present".format(i)
            break
    if flag != "yes":
        print "File not present : {}".format(i)
        tmp.append(False)
```

And also, please suggest if any better approach/method.

Comment: To speak about optimizations, you need some code first. What have you written so far? What is the problem with it? How slow is it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, missed to include code. added now, hope it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ordering in the test1 list is irrelevant, you could use the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function together with a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and thereby avoid temporary variables.

```
for i in l1:
    if any([re.match("^"+str(i)+"$",j) for j in test1]):
        print "File {} present".format(i)
    else:
        print "File not present : {}".format(i)
```

Comment: The `str()` function for the `i` is not necessary for the given example. It might help if some file names only consist of numbers and are not already represented as strings.

Comment: abc_log_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_test-analysis.log, abc_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_sample-analysis.log  , out of these elements in l1, can i replace these groupings into some characters ? like, above strings will look like this after replacing abc_log_ABC_ABC_ABC_test-analysis.log ,  abc_DEF_GHI_JKL_sample-analysis.log

Comment: i can do it in normal string.replace() , but how can i do it in regex ? say if that string containing different patterns (like (\d+) or (.*))

Comment: The comment was meant for filenames ONLY consisting of numbers. Like a file `123456` with no prefix, nor postfix nor extension. As long as you don't get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` from the part where you compose the regex, do not need to replace any numbers or even change file names.

Comment: In if loop, can i get the exact matching value of j ? (as we are matching it any)

Comment: In if loop, can i get the exact matching value of j ? (as we are matching it any)

Comment: For this regex, the exact match is the string in `i`. If you have a more complex regex with e.g. capture groups, you can also iterate over the list comprehension and process the matches individually.